# Difference between SQL Server 2008 vs SQL server 2008 native client?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to know the wt is the exact difference between SQL Server 2008 vs SQL server native client ?

Answer (score 5):

`SQL Server 2008` is a relational database management system.

The `SQL server native client` is a set of dlls that let you access this system and are also used by it and other related software (such as SQL Server tools).

See some information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx).

Comment: thank u but still my doubt is not clear.  SQL server native client. is s/w that is install by default with SQL Server 2008 ?

then wt is the exact use of SQL server native client ?

Comment: @Vishwanath dalvi - it is used internally by SQL server and by SQL Server tools. Why do you need to know more?

Comment: @Vishwanath dalvi - The client access libraries can be installed separately from the SQL Server product itself on a machine which just needs to connect to SQL Server - for instance a web server, application server or functional server.